# Using promises to save, retrieve, and the close the connection?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to the Mongoose library. As a learning exercise, I'm trying to create a new record, retrieve it from the database, log it, and then close the database connection. My code is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function dbOpenCB(callback) {
  console.log('open callback called');
});

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  author: {
    name: String
  }
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

const newPost = new Post({
  title: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  author: {
    name: 'Joe Blow'
  }
});

newPost.save()
  .then(function saveCB(newPost) {
    console.log('newPost:');
    console.dir(newPost);
  })
  .then(Post.where('title', /f.*/).exec())
  .then(function findCB(posts) {
    console.log('Posts:');
    console.dir(posts);
  })
  .then(db.close)
  .end();
```

I end up with the record getting created and logged in the `saveCB`, but the `posts` object is undefined within `findCB` and the database connection is never closed.

It clearly seems that I'm doing something wrong. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mongoose's weird promise API (`.end()` is non-standard). But this should work:

```
var closeDB = db.close.bind(db);
newPost.save()
  .then(function saveCB(newPost) {
    console.log('newPost:');
    console.dir(newPost);
  })
  .then(function(){
    return Post.where('title', /f.*/).exec();
  })
  .then(function findCB(posts) {
    console.log('Posts:');
    console.dir(posts);
  })
  .then(closeDB, closeDB) // always close the db no matter what
  .end(); // wtf is this?
```

Comment: I see my error clearly now. Thank you. And the `end()` method is their library's `done()` method -- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-end